# PHP How to redirect to another page when a particular url come

Tags: php, url, routes

I want to develop a url Router in which when a particular URL comes then I redirect my program to a particular url. Is it even possible? 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: U wanna redirect to different urls everytime? Need more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a HTTP header to redirect to another page:

```
header("Location: foo.php");
```

... or for a full URL:

```
header("Location: http://www.google.co.uk/");
```

Note that you should send headers before any other output (i.e. echo).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to test a 'particular' url, you need to construct it first:

```
$ssl = "";
if ((isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"]=="on") || (isset($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]) && $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]=="443")) 
   { $ssl = "s"; }

$serverport = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]!="80"?":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]:"");

$theurl = "http".$ssl."://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$serverport.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

then, you can test it against another url (or array of them):

```
if ($theurl != $myurl) {
   header("Location: index.php");
}
```

against an array of urls:

```
if (in_array($theurl,$myurls)) {
   header("Location: index.php");
}
```